# bash script variable substitution not happening

Tags: bash

In my bash script I have:

```
HOME_DIR="/root"
EXE_DIR="${HOME_DIR}/exe"
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo '30 3 * * * "${EXE_DIR}/backup"') | crontab -
```

This results in:

```
# crontab -l
30 3 * * * "${EXE_DIR}/backup"
```

How do I get the `EXE_DIR` variable to be substituted into the crontab command?

Comment: `echo "30 3 * * * "${EXE_DIR}/backup"")`

Comment: drmrbrewer: you have the variable in single quotes, so it is a literal `${EXE...}` instead of an expansion. Try `echo "30 3 * * * $EXE_DIR/backup"`

Comment: Inian: that expansion should really be inside quotes, not outside them. `""` is also pointless.